# Nested Query MVC LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to **MVC** and **LINQ**. Currently I faced difficulty on the project and decide to posted up.

My **MVC-View** that I wanted to achieve

```
Cut
----------------------------------
1   20%     
2   40%     
Color
----------------------------------
3   30%    
4   50%     
Perm
----------------------------------
5   10%
```

This is some example of my data table

```
ID  Offer   Service
-------------------
1   20%     Cut
2   40%     Cut
3   30%     Color
4   50%     Color
5   10%     Perm
```

My Controller:

```
var services = (from ps in db.PS
                select ps).Distinct().ToArray();
ViewBag.services = services;
```

My View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.services){
    <h3 class="page-header">
        @item
    </h3>

    //Table TAG INSERT Here: ID, Offer, Service
}
```

PROBLEM comes now, I have no idea on how to populate the data from DB into the view according to their own **Service(eg: Cut, Color, Perm)** in View

I'm thinking of doing this to store the data according to services in my Controller:

```
foreach (var i in services){
    var servicesdata = (from ps in db.PS
                        where ps.Service == i
                        select ps).ToArray();
}
```

I'm wondering can I push the services data that already according to the services into some kind of array so that I can populate into view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `.GroupBy()` clause to group your data by `Service`.  Start by creating view models to represent what you want to display in the view

```
public class OfferVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P0}")]
    public float Offer { get; set; } // assumes you store this as float in the db
}
public class ServiceVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OfferVM> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
IEnumerable<ServiceVM> model = db.PS.GroupBy(x => x.Service).Select(x => new ServiceVM()
{
    Name = x.Key,
    Offers = x.Select(y => new OfferVM()
    {
        ID = y.ID,
        Offer = y.Offer
    })
});
return View(model);
```

And in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<ServiceVM>
@foreach (var service in Model)
{
    <h2>@service.Name</h2>
    foreach (var item in service.Offers)
    {
        <span>@item.ID</span>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Offer)</span>
    }
}
```

Comment: Classic group by question

Comment: Thank You so much @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag is a dynamic property you can insert ViewBag anything but when you retrieve data  from ViewBag, first need to convert it.

```
@foreach (var item in (List<PS>)ViewBag.services){
    <h3 class="page-header">
        @item
    </h3>

    //Table TAG INSERT Here: ID, Offer, Service
}
```

Comment: Yeah understand, but can you elaborate more on the `(List<PS>)ViewBag.Services` ?

Comment: List<PS> PS is your business class first declare namespace on view to uses these  class Ex @Using YourProjectName.WhereYourClassIs like that