# How to query data with calculated fields and map to a ViewModel with a nested ViewModel Collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have referenced numerous questions on this site related to calculated fields and ViewModels, but I can't seem to extrapolate from examples given.  I hope that laying out a specific scenario would allow someone to pin point what I can't see.  I am new to WebApp design in general.  Please take that into consideration.  Also, if I've left off any relevant information, please let me know and I will update the question.

### Here is the scenario:

I have a complex query that is spanning multiple tables to return data used in calculations.  Specifically, I store units for a recipe converted to a base unit and then convert the quantity to the units specified by the user.

I am using AutoMapper to map from entities to ViewModels and vice versa, but I am not sure how to handle the calculated values.  Especially with the nested ViewModel Collection thrown into the mix.

### Option 1

Do I return an autonomous set of data?  Like the following...  and then somehow use AutoMapper to do the mapping?  Perhaps I would need to do the mapping manually, which I haven't found a solid example which includes nested ViewModels.  At this point, I'm not even sure if the following code handles the nested collection correctly for the autonomous data.

```
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var recipes = from u in db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                      from c in db.Categories
                      from r in db.Recipes
                      join ur in db.UserRecipes.Where(u => u.UserId == userId) on r.Id equals ur.RecipeId
                      join mus in db.MeasUnitSystems on ur.RecipeYieldUnitSysId equals mus.Id
                      join muc in db.MeasUnitConvs on mus.Id equals muc.UnitSysId
                      join mu in db.MeasUnits on mus.UnitId equals mu.Id
                      join msy in db.MeasUnitSymbols on mu.Id equals msy.UnitId
                      select new 
                      {
                          Id = c.Id,
                          ParentId = c.ParentId,
                          Name = c.Name,
                          Descr = c.Descr,
                          Category1 = c.Category1,
                          Category2 = c.Category2,
                          Recipes = new 
                          {
                              Id = r.Id,
                              Title = r.Title,
                              Descr = r.Descr,
                              Yield = String.Format("{0} {1}", ((r.Yield * muc.UnitBaseConvDiv / muc.UnitBaseConvMult) - muc.UnitBaseConvOffset), msy.Symbol)
                          }
                      };
```

### Option 2

Another option that crossed my mind was to return the entities and use AutoMapper as I normally would.  Then iterate through the collections and perform the calculations there.  I feel like I could make this work, but it seems inefficient to me because it would result in many queries back to the database.

### Option 3

????  I can't think of any other method to do this.  But, please, if you have suggestions, I am more than willing to hear them.

### Relevant Data

Here is the query returning the data I want in SQL Server (more or less).

```
declare @uid as nvarchar(128) = 'da5435ae-5198-4690-b502-ea3723a9b217'

SELECT  c.[Name] as [Category]
        ,r.Title
        ,r.Descr
        ,(r.Yield*rmuc.UnitBaseConvDiv/rmuc.UnitBaseConvMult)-rmuc.UnitBaseConvOffset as [Yield]
        ,rmsy.Symbol
FROM    Category as c
        inner join RecipeCat as rc on c.Id = rc.CategoryId
        inner join Recipe as r on rc.RecipeId = r.Id
        inner join UserRecipe as ur on r.Id = ur.RecipeId and ur.UserId = @uid
        inner join MeasUnitSystem as rmus on ur.RecipeYieldUnitSysId = rmus.Id
        inner join MeasUnitConv as rmuc on rmus.Id = rmuc.UnitSysId
        inner join MeasUnit as rmu on rmus.UnitId = rmu.Id
        inner join MeasUnitSymbol as rmsy on rmu.Id = rmsy.UnitId
        inner join UserUnitSymbol as ruus on rmsy.UnitId = ruus.UnitId and rmsy.SymIndex = ruus.UnitSymIndex and ruus.UserId = @uid
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Descr { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel> Category1 { get; set; }
    public CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel Category2 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecipeIndexViewModel> Recipes { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeIndexViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Recipe")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Descr { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "YieldUnit")]
    public string Yield { get; set; }
}
```

---

### UPDATE 2/10/2018

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33921573/40521) that does a very good job of explaining exactly what I'm looking at.  Particularly under the **A Better solution ?** section.  Mapping queries directly to my ViewModels looks like it would allow me to get my calculated values as well.  Problem is, the example given is once again too simplistic.

He gives the following DTO's

```
public class UserDto
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;} 
  public UserTypeDto UserType { set; get; }    
}
public class UserTypeDto
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

And does the following for mapping:

```
var users = dbContext.Users.Select(s => new UserDto
{
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    UserType = new UserTypeDto
    {
        Id = s.UserType.Id,
        Name = s.UserType.Name
    }
});
```

Now what if the UserDTO looked like this:

```
    public class UserDto
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;} 
      public ICollection<UserTypeDto> UserTypes { set; get; }    
    }
```

How would the mapping be done if the UserTypes were a collection?

---

### Update 2/13/2018

I feel I am making progress, but am currently headed in the wrong direction.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262391/recursive-linq-query-select-item-and-all-children-with-subchildren) and came up with the following (which currently errors because of the method call in the linq query):

***Note:** I removed Category2 from the ViewModel as I found it was not needed and only complicated this further.

query inside index controller method

```
    IEnumerable<CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel> recipesVM = db.Categories
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
        .Select(x => new CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        ParentId = x.ParentId,
        Name = x.Name,
        Descr = x.Descr,
        Category1 = MapCategoryRecipeIndexViewModelChildren(x.Category1),
        Recipes = x.Recipes.Select(y => new RecipeIndexViewModel()
        {
            Id = y.Id,
            Title = y.Title,
            Descr = y.Descr
        })
    });
```

Recursive Method

```
private static IEnumerable<CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel> MapCategoryRecipeIndexViewModelChildren(ICollection<Category> categories)
{
    return categories
        .Select(c => new CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            ParentId = c.ParentId,
            Name = c.Name,
            Descr = c.Descr,
            Category1 = MapCategoryRecipeIndexViewModelChildren(c.Category1),
            Recipes = c.Recipes.Select(r => new RecipeIndexViewModel()
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Title = r.Title,
                Descr = r.Descr
            })
        });
}
```

At this point, I don't even have the calculations I require, but that doesn't matter until I get this working (small steps).  I quickly discovered you can't really call a method inside a Linq Query.  Then a thought occurs to me, if I need to force the Linq Query to execute and then perform all the mapping on the in memory data, then I would essentially be doing the same thing as **Option 2** (above), but I could perform the calculations within the ViewModel.  This is the solution I will pursue and will keep everyone posted.

Comment: What's the trouble with collections? AutoMapper doesn't have any problem with collection properties as long as 1) the names match or the name mapping is configured explicitly and 2) there's a mapping configuration for the child class. And w.r.t. calculations: these can also be configured in AM using ForMember.

Comment: The only issue I had with collections was if I were to do the mapping myself to get just the data and calculations I wanted, but that was answered by [aakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811265/aakash) and I believe is the wrong direction due to the recursive nature of my Category table. I've used AutoMapper with collection properties successfully, but wasn't sure how to use it when calculations are involved. My current plan is to use EF with AM as intended to bring back all data, including data needed for the calculations, and then do the calculations in the ViewModels. See Update 2/13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!  ...I think.  ...Maybe.  If anything, I'm querying the data, mapping it to my ViewModels and I have the calculations too.  I do have additional questions, but they are a lot more specific.  I will layout the solution I followed and where I think it requires work below.

I basically implemented my **Option 2** from above, but instead of iterating through the collections, I just performed the calculations within the ViewModels.

**Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var recipes = db.Categories.Where(u => u.Users.Any(x => x.Id == userId))
                        .Include(c => c.Category1)
                        .Include(r => r.Recipes
                            .Select(u => u.UserRecipes
                                .Select(s => s.MeasUnitSystem.MeasUnitConv)))
                        .Include(r => r.Recipes
                            .Select(u => u.UserRecipes
                                .Select(s => s.MeasUnitSystem.MeasUnit.MeasUnitSymbols)));

    IEnumerable<CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel> recipesVM = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, IEnumerable<CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel>>(recipes.ToList());

    return View(recipesVM);
}
```

**View Models**

```
public class CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Descr { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel> Category1 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecipeIndexViewModel> Recipes { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeIndexViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Recipe")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Descr { get; set; }

    public double Yield { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRecipeIndexViewModel> UserRecipes { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Yield")]
    public string UserYieldUnit
    {
        get
        {
            return System.String.Format("{0} {1}", ((Yield * 
                        UserRecipes.FirstOrDefault().MeasUnitSystem.MeasUnitConv.UnitBaseConvDiv / 
                        UserRecipes.FirstOrDefault().MeasUnitSystem.MeasUnitConv.UnitBaseConvMult) - 
                        UserRecipes.FirstOrDefault().MeasUnitSystem.MeasUnitConv.UnitBaseConvOffset).ToString("n1"),
                        UserRecipes.FirstOrDefault().MeasUnitSystem.MeasUnit.MeasUnitSymbols.FirstOrDefault().Symbol);
        }
    }
}

public class UserRecipeIndexViewModel
{
    public MeasUnitSystemIndexViewModel MeasUnitSystem { get; set; }
}

public class MeasUnitSystemIndexViewModel
{
    public MeasUnitIndexViewModel MeasUnit { get; set; }

    public MeasUnitConvIndexViewModel MeasUnitConv { get; set; }
}

public class MeasUnitIndexViewModel
{
    public ICollection<MeasUnitSymbolIndexViewModel> MeasUnitSymbols { get; set; }
}

public class MeasUnitConvIndexViewModel
{
    public double UnitBaseConvMult { get; set; }

    public double UnitBaseConvDiv { get; set; }

    public double UnitBaseConvOffset { get; set; }
}

public class MeasUnitSymbolIndexViewModel
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

This appears to be working, but I know it needs some work.

For instance, the relation shown between the Recipe and UserRecipe shows one to many.  In reality, if the UserRecipe were filtered by the current user, the relationship would be one to one.  Also, the same goes for the MeasUnit and the MeasUnitSymbol entities.  Currently, I'm relying on the FirstOrDefault of those collections to actually perform the calculations.

Also, I have seen numerous posts that state that calculations should not be done in the View Models.  Except for some who say it's okay if it is only a requirement of the View.

Last I will say that paying attention to variable names within the ViewModels would have saved me some headaches.  And I thought I knew how to utilize Linq Queries, but had issues with the data returned.  It was easier to rely on the eager loading provided by Entity Framework to bring back the hierarchical data structure needed, versus the flat table structures I'm used to working with.

I'm still new to a lot of this and wrapping my head around some of the quirks of MVC and Entity Framework leaves me brain dead after a few hours, but I will continue to optimize and adopt better programming methods as I go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over UserType Collection and map the value to UserType dto's collection.

Use this code.

```
    var users =  dbContext.Users.Select(s => new UserDto
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.FullName,
    UserType = s.UserType.Select(t => new UserTypeDto
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        Name = t.Name
    }).ToList()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I wish I would have checked back here earlier.  I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759641/nested-query-mvc-linq) whose answer pointed out the same thing.  This takes care of the Recipes property within the CategoryRecipeIndexViewModel view model, but I still need to map Category1 and Category2.  Category1 is a recursive collection and Category 2 is just recursive, which I haven't done any research on yet.  I will be searching for examples now, but if you know how to handle recursive View Models it would greatly help!

Comment: you have asked if UserTypes were a collection?

Comment: Yes, but I only used that example to simplify my question.  The actual View Models I am attempting to populate (see question before the update) are more complicated.

Comment: Something else that I just realized, the example you've given and the examples I've linked to all us Linq Methods.  I find Linq Queries to be more readable.  How would I write it using Linq Queries?